# Why is piped input okay to zenity, but <file malfunctions?

Tags: io-redirection, pipe, zenity

My question is as simple as what the `zenity --text` args say in the example... but what is causing this 100% CPU grab by the redirection?
...(and by the way, is this particular usage of `<` actually called `redirection`. It seems like it is creating a direction, rather than *re*-directing )..

```
echo "Peacocks talking of the colour grey."> test
cat test | zenity --text='This does NOT hog the CPU'   --list --column='#' --width=450 
<test      zenity --text='This hogs 100% of CPU usage' --list --column='#' --width=450
```

I'm quite happy to use `cat test |` (because it isn't useless in this case; it works and < and `|` are somehow different, but I haven't been able to track it down again...

To be clear: `<test` and `cat test |` both work. The zenity dialog appears and is fully functional in both cases, but for as long as the `<test` version of the dialog is kept open, it uses 100% CPU (of one core)... 94% on the single "core" VMs...

Comment: As long as `test` file exists, I do not see any difference.

Comment: I've tried in Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04.. The same thing happens in all of them... (10.10, and 11.04, are recently installed and updated VirtualBox guest VMs. The host is 10.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a bug in zenity. You can see what is going on by using the `strace` tool (I've wrapped the strace lines in this post to make it easier to read).

With the pipe version, this line in strace shows what happens when the pipe is closed (because `cat` exits):

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}], \
     3, 0) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
```

That part at the end - `fd=0, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP`, in particular `POLLHUP` - tells zenity that stdin has hung up (writer of the pipe has gone away). Zenity is processing this correctly and closing fd 0 later.

Files do not get `POLLHUP` events - instead a `read(2)` result of zero means EOF. This is a different code path for zenity. It polls again for fd 0 and this is what it gets:

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=3, events=POLLIN}, {fd=0, events=POLLIN}],\
     3, 0) = 1 ([{fd=0, revents=POLLIN}])
read(0, "", 1024)       = 0
```

That should be the end of it - the zero read should cause zenity to close fd 0. But it doesn't. The strace output above keeps repeating, as zenity keeps polling fd 0. Until fd 0 is closed, it will always be ready for reading, as that is how file descriptors at EOF work, since you need to read it to get the EOF result.

Because zenity is not responding correctly to EOF on stdin, it keeps looping on a `poll(2)`/`read(2)` loop, where `poll` returns immediately, as does `read`. Again, and again and again...

Comment: *@camh*: Wow!... That is some awsome super-sleuthing... I initially couldn't quite understand your explanation, but then something gelled when I read Caleb's comment of, *"sending the data as a stdin pipe vs passing a file descriptor"*... Your explanation became crystal clear!... (so, in summary, I this means: don't use *<file* with *zeinty*, but piping data to it is fine)... Thanks, from a happy camper :)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
zenity --text='This does NOT hog the CPU' --list --column='#' --width=450 <(cat test)
```

Comment: It doesn't hog the CPU, but it also doesn't display the contents of of 'test'. It displays `/dev/fd/63 instead`... but `sed -n p <(cat test)` works fine.. it outputs the correct text... Maybe it is just a *zenity* thing, but I'd still like to know what the diffeence is between *'<test'* and *'cat test |'* that zenity is having problems with.

Comment: This answer should have no effect on the bug, zenity would see this the same as `<test`. The difference is in sending the data as a stdin pipe vs passing a file descriptor to be opened and read by the program.